# Switching Internet Explorer Windows with VBA

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, excel, automation, vba

I have been working on an Excel macro to automate an Internet Explorer process at work. I'm incredibly close to figuring everything out, but at the end, the macro clicks on a "Download Report" button, which launches a new window. I need to initiate a few things on this new window but I cannot figure out how to change the focus of the macro to the new window. I have found a few things online, but they have been unsuccessful. I know there are ways to toggle between browser windows by telling Excel to look for the name of the browser window, and to activate it, but parts of the name of the new window are constantly changing (it's a unique URL for that particular window).

I was wondering if there might be a way to have the Macro look for just the first Nine letters of the window and switch to that window? Similar to the LEFT function in excel? The reason being is that the first 9 characters of the URL never change. The name of the original window (the one I'm trying to switch from) never changes, so maybe I could tell Excel to look for the the Browser Window that is NOT named the original one? Or any other ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you can use `LEFT` in `VBA` aswell. Please provide a copy of your code so we can see where you are up to.

Comment: If you create an InternetExplorer object, you can control the web browser directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the VBA AppActivate command what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the references to the Internet Controls and shell.  You just need to loop through the IE windows and look at the left hand side of the url.  See below

```
Function GetInternetWindow(urlToLookFor as String) As InternetExplorer

Dim winShell As Shell
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set winShell = New Shell
'loop through the windows and look at the urls
For Each ie In winShell.Windows
    If Left(ie.LocationURL, 9) = urlToLookFor Then        
        GetInternetWindow = ie
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: This may be a really silly question, but I am new to VBA. If I wanted to include this function in my other macro process, how do I do that? Do I put the function below my other code and and then call it?